# TeamCity: Update parent build configuration and see reflected in child project

Tags: teamcity, buildconfiguration

I have a parent build template used by 22 projects.

I have added some new build steps into the parent template and I would like these to be available now in all the child projects without having to add them in manually.

Is there a way I can do this? Currently I cannot see them in the child projects

Comment: maybe you want to say template? The child builds are not depends on Parent build steps.

Comment: Yes sorry, you are right, it is a template

Answer (score 0):

Try making a build template. When viewing your build configuration in the upper right hand corner click Actions > Extract Template. This should make your build steps available to children of your project.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I worded my question correctly. I do have a template, and I have updated this and want to see the new build steps I have added in all the child projects that are based on this template